# passing an Image array from one window to another and displaying the images in the new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, window

I am stuck in a peculiar problem.
I have to pass an image array from one HTML window to another on click of a button. The name of the array that I am passing is `compareImageArray` which I have declared as a global variable in `mainPage.html`. 
I am passing this array in a new window like this:

```
 window.open('/comparePopup',compareImageArray,'_blank','popUpWindow', 'status=0,width=620,height=430,resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes')
```

In the `comparePopup.html`, (that is the new window to which I am sending the array), I am trying to get the Image array elements in the HTML elements pic1, pic2, pic3 like this:

```
<div id="comparePicDiv" style="display:block;">
    <img id="pic1">
    <img id="pic2">
    <img id="pic3">
```

This I am doing in javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// alert(compareImageArray[0])
compareImageArray = window.opener.compareImageArray;

var pic1= document.getElementById("pic1");
var pic2= document.getElementById("pic2");       
var pic3= document.getElementById("pic3");

pic1.src = compareImageArray[0];           
pic2.src = compareImageArray[1];
pic3.src = compareImageArray[2];
```

I am able to view the image url in the alert `alert(compareImageArray[0])` which means that the URL has come to this page. However, the `img` tags are not getting populated with these images. What could be the reason for this? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't send array using window.open(). Here's the spec: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

But you can send the array info through the link as query string such as comparePopup.html?pic1_pic2_pic3.... (You need to device a way to send the array info)

In your comparePopup.html, you need Javascript to read query string info and piece back the info into array.

Comment: but then how am i getting the entire image data then in the comparePopup.html (that is the alert message.). The alert gives me the entire data URL of the image. I think the problem lies in the way I am fetching the image or catching it in the image tag. Don't you think so? Is there something very trivial that I am overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue with the help of a friend. As I had suspected, it was not because of the way I was passing the array. The `compareImageArray` is declared global and was being retrieved perfectly in the `comparePopup.html` as confirmed by the alert.

The problem was that since the images are being loaded on body onload and not on any button click, I had to declare the image elements BEFORE the Javascript (which I was not doing.). As a result, it was failing to identify what `pic1`, `pic2` or `pic3` is. 
Now it works fine!